# Changing file permissions on AWS Elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS worker tier environment and I want to change file permissions so i can write logs to file. I have tried doing this in eb extensions .config file but cannot get it to work.

If the command is run (sudo chmod 777 /path/to/file.rb) under the 'commmands:' then its executed before the env is built and does not work.

If its under 'container_commands:' then it also does not work.

I cannot find any guidance on how to do this in the AWS docs (it may of course be there)

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If your challenge is that you need to change the permissions after your application has been deployed, then you'll need to use a post-deploy hook. Unfortunately post-deploy hooks are not officially supported by AWS, but they seem to be pretty widely used.

I done similar things using the technique described here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=493887

Your hook might look something like this:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_change_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chmod 777 /path/to/file.rb
```